# How to To Submit Form data with jquery ajax without refresh the page and get data on request page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Her is My Code 
     **HTML**

```
<form id="msg_form">
<input type="text" name="msg_text">
<button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(function () {

    $('#msg_form').on('send', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'msg.php',
        data: $('#msg_form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

        }
      });

    });

  });
```

**Now I want Want Get The Data On Request Page**
How can I Send Form data and recive it on anthor Page
**Php Code**

```
   $msg_text=$_POST['msg_text'];
   $receiver_id=$_POST['sender_id'];
   $sender_id=$_SESSION['u_id'];
   $sql="INSERT INTO massges (msg_text,sender_id,receiver_id) values('$msg_text', '$sender_id', $receiver_id)";
   $run=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: What language are you using to receive the data with?

Comment: I want to Use Php To Recive data

Comment: OK, so in order to get some PHP developers involved with this, you should tag this question with PHP and then state that you want to be able to retrieve the form data with PHP.  Also, show any PHP code that you have come up with thus far.

Comment: @lipumuna Saw your comment, I'll have something for you momentarily. Do you have any php code that you can post?

Comment: Yes i have  posted now see

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's an approximation. The change I made to the data field is the *proper* way to send data back in an ajax request.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('#msg_form').on('send', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'msg.php',
        data: msg_text: $('input[name="msg_text"]'), /*And if you're posting back anything else from the page, sender_id possibly, define same way*/
        success: function () {
          alert('Posted successfully');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

**php**
Perhaps a bit more elegant than it needed to be but I wasn't sure how far you had gotten and also, again, it is more *proper*.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if($_POST['msg_text'] != '' && $_POST['sender_id'] != '' && $_SESSION['u_id'] != ''){
        $db_connection = sql_connect();
        if($db_connection->connect_errno){
            echo "Failed to connect to db";
        } else {
            $msg_text = $_POST['msg_text'];
            $receiver_id = $_POST['sender_id'];
            $sender_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `massges` (`msg_text`,`sender_id`,`receiver_id`) values('$msg_text', '$sender_id', $receiver_id)";
            if($db_connection->query($sql) === true){
                echo "Successfully inserted data";
            } else {
                echo "Data not inserted";
            }
        }
        $db_connection->close();
    }
}
//connects to db, return true/false for connection status
function sql_connect(){
    return new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database", /*PORT*/ 3306);
}
```

If you can also provide me with any errors you're getting or where it's getting stuck I can probably offer something more.

Comment: i want to insert the data in mysql and dont return anythig

Comment: Its Nothing Happen